# How to sort an array of FileInfo[]

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, .net

I have the following code

```
DirectoryInfo taskDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(this.taskDirectoryPath);
FileInfo[] taskFiles = taskDirectory.GetFiles("*" + blah + "*.xml");
```

I would like to sort the list by filename.

How is this done, as quickly and easily as possible using .net v2.

Comment: BTW, Explorer sort names using natural number comparison, so if you want to achieve similar behavior you must write your own comparer that will split names into strings and numbers chunks, and compare them separately.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Call Array.Sort, passing in a comparison delegate:

```
Array.Sort(taskFiles, delegate(FileInfo f1, FileInfo f2) {
    return f1.Name.CompareTo(f2.Name);
});
```

In C# 3 this becomes slightly simpler:

```
Array.Sort(taskFiles, (f1, f2) => f1.Name.CompareTo(f2.Name));
```

Or you can use a `StringComparer` if you want to use a case-insensitive sort order:

```
Array.Sort(taskFiles,
           (x, y) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
```

(or use `string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name, true)`, or any of the many other ways of comparing strings :)

Comment: @Thomas - but that doesn't do an in-place sort, which is (I believe) what the OP wants

Comment: I would only add that is possible to use vs2008 to target 2.0 using c# 3.0 syntax  ;)

Comment: @kentaromiura : yes, but there isn't only syntax involved here... the System.Core assembly is necessary as well, and isn't available in .NET 2.0. However it should be possible to make it work in 2.0 using LinqBridge (http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/)

Answer (score 9):

```
Array.Sort(taskFiles, delegate (FileInfo x, FileInfo y) {
    return string.Compare(x.Name,y.Name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class FileComparer : IComparer
        {
            public enum CompareBy
            {
                Name /* a-z */,
                LastWriteTime /* oldest to newest */,
                CreationTime  /* oldest to newest */,
                LastAccessTime /* oldest to newest */,
                FileSize /* smallest first */,

            }
            // default comparison
            int _CompareBy = (int)CompareBy.Name;
            public FileComparer()
            {
            }

            public FileComparer(CompareBy compareBy)
            {
                _CompareBy = (int)compareBy;
            }
            int IComparer.Compare( object x, object y )
            {
                int output = 0;
                DirectoryInfo file1 = new DirectoryInfo(x.ToString());
                DirectoryInfo file2 = new DirectoryInfo(y.ToString());
                switch(_CompareBy)
                {
                    case (int)CompareBy.LastWriteTime:
                        output = DateTime.Compare(file1.LastWriteTime, file2.LastWriteTime);
                        break;
                    case (int)CompareBy.CreationTime:
                        output = DateTime.Compare(file1.CreationTime, file2.CreationTime);
                        break;
                    case (int)CompareBy.LastAccessTime:
                        output = DateTime.Compare(file1.LastAccessTime, file2.LastAccessTime);
                        break;
    //              case (int)CompareBy.FileSize:
    //                  output = Convert.ToInt32(file1.Length - file2.Length);
    //                  break;
                    case (int)CompareBy.Name:
                    default:
                        output = (new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare( file1.Name, file2.Name );
                        break;
                }
                return output;
            }
        }

///////////////////////////////////
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();         
            string folder = @"D:\DVRData\ICICI\Transaction\21-Dec-08\08_51_23_2231";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);            
            IComparer comp = new FileComparer(FileComparer.CompareBy.CreationTime);
            Array.Sort(files, comp);
            foreach(string file in files)
            {
                list.Add(file);
            }
```

Comment: There's an awful lot of branching going on inside each compare operation, why not just instantiate a single, specialized comparer for each type of sorting instead?

Comment: Or, save a compare delegate in the constructor, based on the CompareBy parameter and then just execute the delegate in the Compare function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Comparison<FileInfo> comparison = new Comparison<FileInfo>(delegate(FileInfo a, FileInfo b)
{
    return String.Compare(a.Name, b.Name);
});

Array.Sort(taskFiles, comparison);
```

But anyway I think the result of GetFiles is already sorted by name...

Comment: "But anyway I think the result of GetFiles is already sorted by name..." - from MSDN: The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed

Comment: GetFiles return files sorted by name only on NTFS drives, because NTFS stores names as binary tree! This is not valid for FAT or any other file system. So you must always use sort to be sure that output is sorted.