# Sorting the result of Directory.GetFiles in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, getfiles

I have this code to list all the files in a directory.

```
class GetTypesProfiler
{
    static List<Data> Test()
    {
        List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();
        string folder = @"DIRECTORY";
        Console.Write("------------------------------------------\n");
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.dll");
        Stopwatch sw;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {   
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            var fileinfo = new FileInfo(file);
            long fileSize = fileinfo.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", fileName, fileSize);
        }
        return dataList;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

I need to print out the file info based on file size or alphabetical order. How can I sort the result from Directory.GetFiles()?

Comment: Add your data to the list, write a LINQ sorting or a custom IComparer...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199006/how-to-sort-an-array-of-fileinfo-c

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Very easy with LINQ.

To sort by name,

```
var sorted = Directory.GetFiles(".").OrderBy(f => f);
```

To sort by size,

```
var sorted = Directory.GetFiles(".").OrderBy(f => new FileInfo(f).Length);
```

Comment: do you know how are the files sorted in the first place when you retrieve them with Directory.GetFile() ?

Comment: @Bosak: Most likely some order that has to do with the specifics of the filesystem, much like `dir` gives you a consistent but random-looking order.

Comment: On my computer, It gives the files and the directories in alphabetical order. I am using Windows 7

Comment: Can you explain what that lambda is actually doing? It looks to me as if its returning itself, but that makes little sense.

Comment: @kingfrito_5005 those lambdas simply map each value in the collection to be sorted to an arbitrary sort value -- this allows e.g. to sort integers by their absolute value with `i => Math.Abs(i)`. But there are many cases where we have a collection of comparable values and we just want to sort it without any fancy projections. Sort integers by value? `OrderBy(i => i)`. Sort strings by value? `OrderBy(s => s)`. In this instance we are sorting filenames (strings) exactly like that.

Answer (score 15):

To order by date: (returns an enumerable of FileInfo):

```
Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.dll").Select(fn => new FileInfo(fn)).
                                    OrderBy(f => f.Length);
```

or, to order by name:

```
Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.dll").Select(fn => new FileInfo(fn)).
                                    OrderBy(f => f.Name);
```

Making `FileInfo` instances isn't necessary for ordering by file name, but if you want to apply different sorting methods on the fly it's better to have your array of `FileInfo` objects in place and then just `OrderBy` them by `Length` or `Name` property, hence this implementation. Also, it looks like you are going to create `FileInfo` anyway, so it's better to have a collection of `FileInfo` objects either case.

Sorry I didn't get it right the first time, should've read the question and the docs more carefully.

Comment: GetFiles returns a string array, not fileinfo.

Comment: This doesn't sort by file length, it sorts by **filename** length.

Comment: That will sort on length of filenames, not length of files themselves.

Answer (score 7):

You can use LINQ if you like, on a FileInfo object:

```
var orderedFiles =  Directory.GetFiles("").Select(f=> new FileInfo(f)).OrderBy(f=> f.CreationTime)
```

Comment: To get newest files first:   var orderedFiles =  Directory.GetFiles("").Select(f=> new FileInfo(f)).OrderByDescending(f=> f.CreationTime)

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] arrFi = di.GetFiles("*.*");
Array.Sort(arrFi, delegate(FileInfo x, FileInfo y) { return StrCmpLogicalW(x.Name, y.Name); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if you only need to sort by file name and the file title supports the ascending or descending logical order.I add variables to have a bit more control of the source and search pattern.

```
Using Dir = System.IO;

string Source = yourVariable;
string SearchPattern = yourVariable;

Dir.Directory.GetFiles(Source, SearchPattern, Dir.SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Getting Directory object
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);

// getting files for this folder
FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();

// Sorting using the generic Array.Sort function based on Names comparison
Array.Sort(files, delegate (FileInfo x, FileInfo y) { return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name); });

// Sorting using the generic Array.Sort function based on the creation date of every folder
Array.Sort(files, delegate (FileInfo x, FileInfo y) { return DateTime.Compare(x.CreationTime, y.CreationTime); });
```

[Array Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-6.0#system-array-sort(system-array-system-collections-icomparer))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).