# .NET 4.0 - Are the results of Directory.GetFiles always guaranteed to be sorted by filename?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, io

I was wondering, in .NET 4.0+, are the results of `Directory.GetFiles` always guaranteed to be  sorted by file name in ascending order?


Please note that I'm not asking how to sort the results, this I know how to do (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294333/1203288), I just want to know if I have to sort them manually or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. From MSDN:

> The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort() method if a specific sort order is required.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx

Answer (score 7):

No.  From the documentation for [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx):

> The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort() method if a specific sort order is required.

Comment: sorry to not mark your answer as the correct one. you and DaveZych seemed to post at the exact same time with the exact same answer, so I marked his answer as correct since he has a much lower reputation than you.

Comment: @Brandon You can mouseover the `answered Oct 15 at 20:55` on an answer for a more exact time - Reed was actually first, by 9 seconds!

Comment: @Bridge Ha, good to know, I'll remember that for the future. They were both good answers and I did upvote them both.