# How to sort DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()

Tags: c#, sorting, fileinfo

I am creating the image of the PowerPoint file programmatically. And after saving the Images to the local drive I am getting the files using `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`.
I am saving the image files with the sequence numbers.

My Files:
[image]

My issue is when I get the files, are not in the sequence I need them in.
The files sequence which I am getting in the `FileInfo[]` is :

[image]

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294275/sorting-the-result-of-directory-getfiles-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842/sorting-directory-getfiles

Comment: @bansi: I don't have found solution in that questions that's why I asked. Please check the question again. Thank you.

Comment: I have voted for re-open. by the time check this. `const Int32 templateLength = 4;/*size of the filename template (till the numeric part starts)*/
foreach (FileInfo info in dInfo.GetFiles().OrderBy(fi => fi.Name.Substring(0, templateLength)).ThenBy(fi => Conversion.Val(fi.Name.Substring(templateLength)))) {
 Debug.Print(info.Name);
}`

Comment: Guys, you've chosen incorrect duplicate question. It's [Natural Sort Order in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp) OP is looking for.

Comment: @bansi Thank you for this replay. I am still trying on it.

Comment: the best answer for me was here :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e4ec8ae3-dc6e-4027-8fed-1be69b6a1462/sorting-a-list-with-alphanumeric-names?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 5):

The function doesn't make any guarantees about order but you can achieve the desired result with a simple LINQ query;

```
   FileInfo[] sortedFiles = DirectoryInfo.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in directory.GetFiles().OrderBy(fi=>fi.FileName))
{

}
```