# How to sort files by date in file name using c#?

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have many files in a folder. Those files have date and time in the file name in specific format. I need to extract the date from the name and then sort it by date in ascending order. 
File Name example :-

> format_type_2011-07-12-13-00-12.txt

Earlier I was using by createTime. But now requirement is changed.

```
var Files = new DirectoryInfo(FileDirectory).GetFiles()
                                                            .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
                                                            .ToList();
```

How do i do it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: write a function to extract the date and replace the question marks with a call to that function....?

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199006/how-to-sort-an-array-of-fileinfo-c

Comment: Are the files accessed or updated after the initial creation? Is there a reason you cannot use the FileInfo.CreationTime (or LastWriteTime) property?

Comment: No Can't use FileInfo.CreationTime anymore. Coz sometimes Files are uploaded in one shot using FTP...that keeps the creationTime same for all the files..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(FileDirectory);
var Files = di.GetFiles()
              .OrderBy( f => f.Name.Substring(f.Name.LastIndexOf('_')+1)
              .ToList();
```

Since your file names (minus the format info) are already in ISO8601 order (year first, then month, then date, etc.) you can just sort based on the string w/o having to convert to a date.

Comment: Seems like should but it doesn't. "At least one object must implement IComparable".

Answer (score 2):

You can use ordinary string operators in your orderby statement to exract the part you want to sort on:

```
    string f1 = "Foo_2011-07-12-13-00-12.txt";
    string f2 = "Bar_2011-07-12-13-00-15.txt";
    string f3 = "Blah_2011-07-12-13-00-11.txt";

    int sortRelevant = "0000-00-00-00-00-00.txt".Length;

    List<string> files = new List<string>() { f1, f2, f3 };

    var sorted = (from f in files orderby f.Substring(f.Length - sortRelevant) select f);

    foreach (string fs in sorted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fs);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think LastWriteTime is what you are looking for. Here is the MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx

also the link to FileInfo if needed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx

Comment: No LastWriteTime is not I am looking for. I need to sort files by date and time and this date comes from the File Name itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are close:

```
var Files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\").GetFiles()
                                     .OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime)
                                     .ToArray(); //or .ToList() whatever suits you best
```

Comment: @Adrain. I need to sort it by date and time from file name. I can't use FileInfo.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code should work for you:

```
var Files = new DirectoryInfo(@"W:\").GetFiles().OrderBy(f=> f.LastWriteTime).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Files = new DirectoryInfo(FileDirectory)
                   .GetFiles()
                   .OrderBy(f => f.Name.Substring(f.Name.Length - 23, 19)
                   .ToList();
```